# Is it possible to get FTP access with GitHub Page?

Tags: ftp

I want to make a website using GitHub Pages but can I get FTP access for the website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it's not possible. GitHub Pages is for intended for Git users and projects, it is not intended for people looking for a free web host. To use GitHub you must use a GIT compatible client or the terminal.

If you want to host your website on GIT then you need to add a repository and upload your files using `git commit` and `git push`, then once you have uploaded your repository you then need to clone it to GitHub Pages like so:

- `git clone https://github.com/username/username.github.io`

Comment: [Github blog confirming this answer](https://github.com/blog/272-github-pages)